# Install .mobileconfig OTA to device without using Profile Manager web interface

Tags: server.app, profile-manager, apns, configuration-profiles

I have a Mac Mini running the current El Capitan public release and Server app. Server is running the Profile Manager module, and I have an iPhone 5S which is both in supervised mode and enrolled to the Mac Mini.

If I want to change the configuration of the device, I can log into the web backend of Profile Manager, change the config and submit it - which works great. Instead of logging in each time I want to change the profile, **I'd like to automate the push of a new configuration profile to this device, wirelessly**.

There's a workflow in the *Apple Configurator 2* app called *Install Profiles on Devices.action* which does just this, with the catch that the device must be physically connected to the Mac.

*cfgutil* (which ships with Xcode) has a command called *install-profile* which is what the Automator workflow performs, like this for example:

```
cfgutil -C test.crt -K test.key -e 0x0000000000000 install-profile profile.mobileconfig
```

As before, it requires the device to be physically connected to the Mac. (it works great, and installs the profile silently too - as the device is in supervised mode)

Does anyone know of a method to install this profile wirelessly to a known device under the control of Profile Manager?

Comment: I believe you can push this out wirelessly using OS X Server. Have you tried that?

Comment: @NoahL Yes, it is true it works wirelessly using the web UI within Profile Manager, but I'd like to automate this task and specify my own .mobileconfig file.